# python function to read input lines from the user and return pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a function which reads input lines from the user until the user presses Enter. Each line should contain first the index and then the corresponding value, separated by whitespace. These index and values will be used in the function to return a pandas series. Malformed input should cause an exception. An input line is malformed, if it is non-empty and, when split at whitespace, does not result in two parts. My function looks:

---

```
def read_series():
    val = []
    ind = []
    while True:
        x = input("Give index and value for the series(sep by whitespace): ")

        try:
            res = x.split(' ')
            ind.append(res[0])
            val.append(res[1])
        except ValueError:
            break
    return pd.Series(val, index=ind)
```

---

running the function gives error:

---

```
val.append(res[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

I am unable to understand while res has two elements then why res[1] raises an error. Someone can help me save time.

Answer (score 0):

You should except an `IndexError` instead of a `ValueError` as noted in the error message.

You should also try to get the value first. If not, when you give a input without space, your index does not have the same length than your values and you can't create the `Series`.

```py
def read_series():
    val = []
    ind = []
    while True:
        x = input("Give index and value for the series(sep by whitespace): ")
        res = x.split(' ')
        try:
            val.append(res[1])
            ind.append(res[0])
        except IndexError:
            break
    return pd.Series(val, index=ind)
```